# weak type estimate for Hardy Littlelewood maximal function Mf

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

The question is $1<p<\infty$, prove that $\|Mf\|_{L^{p,\infty}}\lesssim\|f\|_{L^{p,\infty}}$
I want to prove that for $p=1$, $Mf$  is of restricted weak type (1,1), 
i.e.$\exists C, \;s.t.\;\forall \;\text{measurable set}\;A $ satisfying $\mu(A)<\infty, \|M\chi_A\|_{L^{1,\infty}} \le C {\mu(A)}$
It suffices to consider $A $ cube.  (1)

By the rearrangement invariance of $L^{1,\infty}$ norm, WLOG A is a cube centered at $O$ of length 2$a$.
$$M\chi_A(x)\sim_n M\chi_{B(0,a)}(x)\sim_n (\frac{a}{\lvert x \rvert +a})^n$$
$$\Rightarrow\mu\{x: M\chi_A(x) >\lambda\}\sim_n \frac{a^n}{\lambda}\;\Rightarrow\|M\chi_A\|_{L^{1,\infty}} \lesssim_n  {\mu(A)}$$
I am wondering whether my proof is correct, especially (1). If (1) is wrong, then I want to know how to prove the origin problem.
Thank you all!

Comment: How are you justifying the very first comparison? It's not obvious to me that $\chi_A$ and $\chi_{B(0,a)}$ have comparable maximal functions.

Comment: Note that A is a cube, we can find two balls inside and outside , with radius comparable with a. More precisely, first get the second estimate, two balls with comparabe radius will have comparable maximal function

Comment: Oh, right. I missed that assumption. Then my gripe is indeed with the reduction to $A$ being a cube. Such an argument would probably use linearity (or sublinearity) in some way, but the weak "norms" are only quasi-norms.

Comment: I am also not sure. But I think if there are finite cubes, Mf(x) will be the ball "exactly" containing x and the nearest ball. If the ball contain many cubes, then it might be somehow average, thus smaller. But this is just something inituitive, I am looking for a precise way or just another approch to the origin problem.

Comment: Another approach: Notice that the restricted bound is implied by the usual weak (1,1) bound for $M$ (i.e. $M:L^1\to L^{1,\infty}$). There's a bunch of different ways to prove this that you can search for online.

Comment: Oh, yes, thank you.